# How JWT validation is done

Tags: authentication, jwt

I read that when using JSon Web Token we don't need to store anything in database. We can then get the id of user without looking to database. How is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you decode an JWT, the payload consists of several 'claims'. (=properties).
In oAuth or OpenIdConnect the 'sub' claim uniquely identifies the user in the inquired system. So, this could be seen as an ID as you put it.

This is the very, very short version....

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Validate Token in  Jwt Middleware Class that Invoke Method fire in every request for Authorization

```
JwtMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly TokenValidationParameters _tokenValidationParams;
        public JwtMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, TokenValidationParameters 
        tokenValidationParams)
        {
            _next = next;
            _tokenValidationParams = tokenValidationParams;
        }

    

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
            {
            try{
                var token = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault()?.Split(" ").Last();
    
                var jwtTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                // Validation 1 - Validation JWT token format
                var tokenInVerification = jwtTokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, _tokenValidationParams, out var validatedToken);
    
                if (validatedToken is JwtSecurityToken jwtSecurityToken)
                {
                    var result = jwtSecurityToken.Header.Alg.Equals(SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    
                    if (result == false)
                    {
                        Error Invalid = new Error()
                        {
                            Success = false,
                            Errors = "Token is Invalid"
                        };
    
                        context.Items["Error"] = Invalid;
                    }
                }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Error Invalid = new Error()
                {
                    Success = false,
                    Errors = "Token does not match or may expired."
                };
                context.Items["Error"] = Invalid ; // userService.GetById(userId);
            }
                await _next(context);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey there check this out 
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatingjwt
might give you an idea of how it works.

Comment: write your own answer otherwise links add as comments